# Tracking readership of a PDF document

Tags: pdf, monitoring, tracking

Background. As some of you know I Publish a business deals listings magazine in PDF format. I am after Google Analytics/Matomo style tracking of readership of the PDF. (I use Matomo for my websites and prefer it over google)

Where I want to get to for example is User one spent 3 seconds on Page 1 skipped page 2, read pages 3-10 left.
User 2 read pages 20-30 and spent an average of 5 seconds on each page. Etc Etc,

Is there a way to do this or is it even possible?

I already know if the magazine has been downloaded and where and when and have this data.

Many thanks

Comment: You can track various actions taken withing the PDF using the Adobe Embed API when the PDF is hosted but once it's downloaded, you can't be sure of what viewer is being used so you can't really track data.

Comment: And not only the viewer is the problem, documents may be shared and read in environments without internet connectivity. How do you expect to get information from there?